# Find the solutions in prime numbers of the following equation: $p^4+q^4+r^4+119=s^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the solutions in **prime numbers** of the following equation: $$p^4+q^4+r^4+119=s^2$$
I am not able to do anything about this problem and don't know from where should I start.

I found the squares of prime numbers after $119$ and then calculated $s^2-119$ and checked whether the sum of three different square primes is equal to $s^2-119$.

After this, I am not able to do anything. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reduce $(mod \ 2)$, $(mod \ 3)$ and $(mod \ 5)$ and consider quadratic residues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation to solve for all variables being prime numbers is

$$p^4 + q^4 + r^4 + 119 = s^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Due to symmetry, WLOG let $p \le q \le r$. If all of $p$, $q$ and $r$ are odd primes, then the left side would be even, but $s \gt 2$ so this is not possible. Thus, $p = 2$, so \eqref{eq1A} would then be

$$q^4 + r^4 + 135 = s^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

If neither $q$ nor $r$ are $3$, then $q^4 \equiv r^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, so the left side would be congruent to $2$ modulo $3$, but $s \gt 3$, so $s^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. This means $q = 3$, with \eqref{eq2A} then becoming

$$r^4 + 216 = s^2 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

We could move $r^4$ to the right side to get a difference of squares & factor, i.e., $(s - r^2)(s + r^2)$, and then use the factors of $216 = 2^3(3^3)$. However, as [Jorge](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/942114/jorge)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301995/find-the-solutions-in-prime-numbers-of-the-following-equation-p4q4r4119#comment8959808_4301995) suggests, it's simpler & easier to check modulo $5$ instead. Since $r \not\equiv 0 \pmod{5} \; \to \; r^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, the left side would be congruent to $2$ modulo $5$. However, all squares are congruent to $0$, $1$ or $4$ modulo $5$, so this is not possible. Thus, $r = 5$ and \eqref{eq3A} is then

$$841 = s^2 \; \; \to \; \; s = 29 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This means $p$, $q$ and $r$ are $2$, $3$ and $5$ in some order, and $s = 29$.

Answer (score 3):

if none of p,q,r are divisible by 5, then $s^2\equiv 2\pmod5$
contradiction
so at least one of p,q,r is divisible by 5
if none of p,q,r are divisible by 3, then $s^2\equiv 2\pmod3$
contradiction
so at least one of p,q,r is divisible by 3
if none of p,q,r are divisible by 2, then s is even, s=2
contradiction
so at least one of p,q,r is divisible by 2
$\{p,q,r\}=\{2,3,5\}\implies s=29$